# Java Socks v4 Proxy

Tags: java, proxy, socks

Can u help me, I have the same problem that described here: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6964547

Java works good with Socks 5 proxy, but with socks 4 proxy:

```
java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
```

The source like:
            URL obj = new URL(url);

```
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("host", *port*));


        con.setConnectTimeout(Config.CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        con.setReadTimeout(Config.READ_TIMEOUT);


        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", Config.USER_AGENT);

        con.setDoOutput(false);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");


        con.connect();
```

I checked a lot of v4 proxy, they don't work.
Also does not help adding prop:

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyVersion", "4");
```

Any ideas about this problem ?:D

Thanks for help.

Comment: There is no such property as `socksProxyVersion.` See [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Answer (score 0):

With JDK 7 they did add `socksProxyVersion` property but you can not set it for individual connections.

The proposed, `socksProxyVersion`, property does not have any impact of SOCKS proxies set programatically through `java.net.Proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this, it works very good:

```
Socket s;
try {
    s = new Socket(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxy));
    s.setSoTimeout(5000);
    s.connect(google);
    s.close();
} catch(Throwable t) {
    s = new Socket(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxy));
    Method m = s.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getImpl");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    Object sd = m.invoke(s);
    m = sd.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setV4");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(sd);
    s.setSoTimeout(5000);
    s.connect(google);
    s.close();
}
```